# Exception while creating Quote in CRM using GenerateQuoteFromOpportunity through javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Here is my code which was generated from CRMRestBuilder;

```
var parameters = {};
parameters.OpportunityId = "guide here..."; // I removed the guid for security purpose

var generateQuoteFromOpportunityRequest = {
    OpportunityId: parameters.OpportunityId,

    getMetadata: function() {
        return {
            boundParameter: null,
            parameterTypes: {
                "OpportunityId": {
                    "typeName": "Edm.Guid",
                    "structuralProperty": 1
                }
            },
            operationType: 0,
            operationName: "GenerateQuoteFromOpportunity"
        };
    }
};

Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(generateQuoteFromOpportunityRequest).then(
    function success(result) {
        if (result.ok) {
            var results = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
);
```

I am getting the following exception while calling;

> > An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: Cannot convert the literal 'undefined'
> > to the expected type 'Edm.Guid'. ---> System.FormatException: Guid
> > should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes
> > (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).    at
> > System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String
> > failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String
> > failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)    at
> > System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithNoStyle(String guidString, GuidResult&
> > result)    at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags,
> > GuidResult& result)    at System.Guid..ctor(String g)    at
> > Microsoft.OData.ODataPayloadValueConverter.ConvertStringValue(String
> > stringValue, Type targetType)    at
> > Microsoft.OData.ODataPayloadValueConverter.ConvertFromPayloadValue(Object
> > value, IEdmTypeReference edmTypeReference)    --- End of inner
> > exception stack trace ---    at
> > Microsoft.OData.ODataPayloadValueConverter.ConvertFromPayloadValue(Object
> > value, IEdmTypeReference edmTypeReference)    at
> > Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ODataV4.CrmPrimitivePayloadValueConverter.ConvertFromPayloadValue(Object
> > value, IEdmTypeReference edmTypeReference)    at
> > Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReaderUtils.ConvertValue(Object
> > value, IEdmPrimitiveTypeReference primitiveTypeReference,
> > ODataMessageReaderSettings messageReaderSettings, Boolean
> > validateNullValue, String propertyName, ODataPayloadValueConverter
> > converter)    at
> > Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightPropertyAndValueDeserializer.ReadPrimitiveValue(Boolean
> > insideJsonObjectValue, IEdmPrimitiveTypeReference
> > expectedValueTypeReference, Boolean validateNullValue, String
> > propertyName)    at
> > Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightPropertyAndValueDeserializer.ReadNonEntityValueImplementation(String
> > payloadTypeName, IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference,
> > PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector,
> > CollectionWithoutExpectedTypeValidator collectionValidator, Boolean
> > validateNullValue, Boolean isTopLevelPropertyValue, Boolean
> > insideResourceValue, String propertyName, Nullable`1 isDynamicProperty)    at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightParameterDeserializer.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ReadNextParameter>b__0(PropertyParsingResult propertyParsingResult, String parameterName)    at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightDeserializer.ProcessProperty(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector, Func`2 readPropertyAnnotationValue,
> > Action`2 handleProperty)    at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightParameterDeserializer.ReadNextParameter(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector)    at Microsoft.OData.ODataParameterReaderCore.ReadImplementation()    at Microsoft.OData.ODataParameterReaderCore.InterceptException[T](Func`1
> > action)    at
> > Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ODataV4.CrmODataActionPayloadDeserializer.Read(ODataMessageReader
> > messageReader, Type type, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)    at
> > System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type
> > type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger
> > formatterLogger)

Please advise if someone knows the root cause and how to fix it.

Comment: Any followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot convert the literal 'undefined' to the expected type 'Edm.Guid'. ---> System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

The above error message clearly says the GUID is not received as expected and instead 'undefined' text being sent. Make sure that is in correct format, exclude {} in guid content if any.

If it’s dynamic guid value, try to debug and hard code some known opportunity Id for troubleshooting. If you have plugin registered in that action, put some trace and/or use profiler for troubleshooting.

GUID is not something like password, so it’s not so secured and useless without other details. So you can share here and if needed change some characters or numbers in GUID, or even you can mask some of the characters.